# Tensorflow object detection API not detecting objects in images of different size than training set

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working on a project using the Tensorflow Object Detection API. I have trained my model on several [test images](https://github.com/marcoistasy/imagineOCR/tree/develop/imagineOCR/example_data/images) and have trained a `rfcn_resnet101_coco` model to detect the letter *o* in these images.

I thought the model was working fine as it was detecting *o* (with decent accuracy) in the images I was passing to it. Please see [here](https://github.com/marcoistasy/imagineOCR/blob/develop/imagineOCR/example_data/test/results/image2_result.png) and [here](https://github.com/marcoistasy/imagineOCR/blob/develop/imagineOCR/example_data/test/results/image3_result.png) for examples.

However, when I passed in two more images whose size varied greatly from the first two, the model was unable to detect anything! For example, when I passed in a [full page](https://github.com/marcoistasy/imagineOCR/blob/develop/imagineOCR/example_data/test/results/image1_result.png) or a [single world](https://github.com/marcoistasy/imagineOCR/blob/develop/imagineOCR/example_data/test/results/image4_result.png) to the model, the output was the same as the input.

I believe this is because the last two images I passed in where much larger or smaller than the [original training set](https://github.com/marcoistasy/imagineOCR/tree/develop/imagineOCR/example_data/images) that I used to train the model, whereas the first two or roughly the same size.

I am wondering if there is anyway to train my model such that it can detect the letter *o* in images of varying sizes and not just those similar to the training input. I thought of tweaking my `pipeline.config` (found [here](https://github.com/marcoistasy/imagineOCR/blob/develop/imagineOCR/example_data/model/pipeline.config)) but am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is never a good practice to train on images in a specific manner and then test it on significantly different scenario, input size in particular. 
That is, unless your model/training scheme is dealing with this difference in some way.

Moreover, many object detectors use anchors as reference boxes, meaning the model trains and then predicts objects with respect to them. These have specific sizes with respect to the input resolution. If you're training such that the ground truth objects' sizes correspond to the anchor sizes, but then test it such that no anchors fit the objects you wish to detect (either too small or too large), then it won't detect them.

This means you need to:

1. Have anchors which correspond to the sizes (and aspect ratios) of the objects you want to detect.
2. Make sure you have ground truth objects which correspond to these anchors in the training set, so that your model will actually learn from such cases.